# When loading the screen, data is not loaded from the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, get

I ran into a problem.  when the page load, data is not loaded from the server, but when the page is saved again, everything works.
Perhaps the problem is related to Async Storage, which does not have time to give a token for a get request.

```
const tokenParse = async () =>{
    const token = await (AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_token'));
    setvalue(JSON.parse(token))
}
const LoadData = async (message) =>{
    try{
        const value = await (AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_token'));
        parsedValue = JSON.parse(value);
        if (value !== null) {

            const token = {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                params:{
                    token: parsedValue,
                }
                
            }
            const LoadTasks = async () =>{
                const get = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}/api/get`, token) 
                setmessage(get.data.response.tasks);
                setObject(Object.values(message));
                console.log(1);
            }
            LoadTasks()
        }
    }catch (error) {
        console.log('Ошибка при получении значения из AsyncStorage', error);
       }
    finally {
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
    tokenParse();
    LoadData(message)        
}, []);
return(
{object?.map((object, index) => {
return(
    <Text key={object.someProperty} style={{color: 'black', marginTop: 5, marginLeft: '2%',}}>     {object.task_name}</Text>

                                )
                            }
                        )})
```

When loading the screen, data is not loaded from the server.

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncStorage` has been removed from the latest versions of React Native and should no longer be used, there are synchronous alternatives such as [react-native-mmkv](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-mmkv) and [others](https://reactnative.directory/?search=storage) that would most likely solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

In LoadData function, await LoadTasks() instead of LoadTasks().
In useEffect(), message,the parameter of LoadData(), is unclear.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).